# fixed position acting responsive

Tags: html, css

Right now it keeps scrolling to the right with the page when it is resized. I want it to stay the same when resized.I put it in a codepen so it would be easier to understand. For some reason the div containing the p tags isn't acting like it is fixed and is instead having the p tags stay responsive to the page size.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XJMJWp

```
<div id = "contents">
<div class = "add" align = "center">
<p id = "entry" style = "position: fixed;margin-left:1163px;margin-top:415px;">One</p>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#contents .add{
width: 1600px;
height: 750px;
margin: auto; position: fixed; top: 0; left:0; bottom:0; right:0;
font-family: "Cedarville Cursive","Lato";
}

#contents{
width: 1600px;
height: 750px;
margin: auto; position: absolute; top: 0; left:0; bottom:0; right:0;
font-family: "Cedarville Cursive","Lato";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of `margin: auto;` this is causing the `#contents .add` element to center itself when the viewport is larger than 1600px.